# STOP sending new user registration password as plain text in Wordpress through email

Tags: wordpress

When a new user register on a WooCommerce site user got an email about confirmation message which contain the current registration info with username and password. The main issue is the password is pain text like

```
Username = xcorola 
Password = 123456
```

How can I stop sending plain text password to user email. or is there any way to override the `wp_new_user_notification()` ?

```
$message = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user - > user_login)."\r\n";
$message. = sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass)."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question as I ran into to the exact same problem! I have spend over 10 hours digging into the Wordpress backend to find the responsible function, and lucky for anyone in the future, I found the following neat solution!

How to make Wordpress new user registration email contain a 'set password'-link, instead plain-text password:

In the first step we will create our own function to return a set-password url. You can simply add this codeblock in `Themes` → `Theme editor` → `functions.php` (right pane)

```
/**
 * This function invokes the get_password_reset_key to invoke generation of a nonce in the backend db,
 * and returns the key. It then constructs a http query to the lost-password endpoint
 * M.G.Poirot 2021
 */
function get_password_reset_link( $user_login = null ) {
        $base_url = wc_get_endpoint_url( 'lost-password', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) );
        $userdata = get_user_by('login', $user_login);
        $user_id = $userdata -> ID;
        $key = get_password_reset_key( $userdata );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $key ) ) {
            $base_url .= '?' . http_build_query( array ( 'key' => $key, 'id' => $user_id ) ) ;
        }
        // If retrieving the key fails, we still return the url that sends the user
        // to enter their e-mail and start the regular password reset procedure.
        return $base_url;
}
```

In this second step we will make the e-mail template editable that is currently sending plain text passwords. For me I had to follow the following buttons, but it might differ depending on your application:

1. Go to `Woocommerce` → `Settings` → `E-mails` → `New account` → `Manage`
   Press `Copy to Theme`. This will make it possible to edit this
   e-mail template
2. Now go to this template. You can find it at `Themes` → `Theme editor` → `Theme files` (right pane) → `woocommerce` → `emails` → `customer_new_account.php`
3. Here, replace:

```
<p>
    <?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?>
</p>
```

With:

```
<p>
    <a class="link" href="<?php echo get_password_reset_link( $user_login ); ?>"><?php // phpcs:ignore ?>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Click here to set your password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </a>
</p>
```

Hope this works for everyone. People with more knowledge about PHP can probably add the clarity and robustness of the function!

Comment: If you can for some reason not follow this or settings are missing, it might be usefull to know that under "WooCommerce"->"Settings"->"Accounts and privacy"->"Account creation" I have checked "create password upon account creation". This might affect the email template content.